# Custom sort of a SortedSet in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, sortedset

I have a sortedSet with following data:

```
aga12
aga44
dp1
dp11
reg13
reg45
sat5
sat6
```

I would like this list to be sorted aphabetically but I want the dp values to be on top so like this:

```
dp1
dp11
aga12
aga44
reg13
reg45
...
```

Anyone know how I can custom sort this SortedSet. I am using VB.NET

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort using a custom compare class

```
  Dim myList As New List(Of String)
  .... 
  myList.Sort(New DpCompare)
```

And

```
  Private Class DpCompare
        Implements IComparer(Of String)


        Public Function Compare(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of String).Compare

            Dim isDPx As Boolean = x.StartsWith("dp")
            Dim isDPy As Boolean = y.StartsWith("dp")

            If isDPx AndAlso isDPy = False Then
                Return -1
            End If

            If isDPy AndAlso isDPx = False Then
                Return 1
            End If

            Return String.Compare(x, y)

        End Function
    End Class
```